# Ionic 4 react white screen on android 5.1

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-react

chrome developer error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEdus.jpg)

build apk by **capacitor** works will in android 7 but shows a white screen in android 4.4, 5.1 and 6